# How am I connecting to AD without specifying the server?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, active-directory

How is it that I can query ActiveDirectory in my development environment when I am not explicitly setting the location of the AD server?

All I am doing is:

```
 WindowsIdentity windowsIdentity = filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.LogonUserIdentity;

 ActiveDirectoryService activeDirectoryService = new ActiveDirectoryService();


 ActiveDirectoryGroups = activeDirectoryService.GetActiveDirectoryGroups(windowsIdentity);
```

When I push to another server I get a permissions issue.

> 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.

Comment: I suspect that when you are running locally the MVC app is running under your domain credentials, however when running on another server under IIS the site will be using the AppPool account which appears (from your question) not to be a domain account.

Comment: If ActiveDirectoryService is your own class, please show some code of the constructor and GetActiveDirectoryGroups method